# Easiest way to put many & in the blank row of the table

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{booktabs,pdflscape,longtable,array}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\usepackage[legalpaper,left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\selectlanguage{bengali}#1}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.18cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{0.4cm}|
>{\selectlanguage{english}}p{0.5cm}|
>{\selectlanguage{english}}p{0.37cm}|p{0.9cm}*{52}{|p{0.145cm}}}
\hline
 &  নাম &  রুম নং &  \MC{ডিপার্টমেন্ট}  &  \MC{বর্ষ} &  জেলা & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}January}& \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}February} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}March} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}April} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}May} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}June} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}July} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}Augest} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}Setember} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}October} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}November} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\selectlanguage{english}December}\\
\cline{7-54}
&&&&&&1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আল -হেলাল & ১৪০৬ & CSE & MS & রংপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আতাউল্লাহ খান & ১৪০৬ & Phy & 4th & কিশোরগঞ্জ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মুতাহহার & ১৪০৬ & Phar & 3rd & গাইবান্ধা &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ রাজিন সালেহ & ১৪০৬ & phy & 4th & শেরপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ শাকিরুল & ১৪০৬ & Botany & 4th & লালমনিরহাট &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আহমদ মুসা & ১২০১ & Chem & MS & নওগাঁ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মশিউর & ১২০১ & Math & 3rd & দিনাজপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ জিহাদ & ১২০১ & Phar & 3rd & বরিশাল &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ খায়রুল & ১২০১ & BioChem & 2nd & গাজীপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মনির & ১২০১ & Botany & 2nd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ তৌহিদ & ১৪০১ & Phy & 3rd & চাঁদপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ সাকলাইন & ১৪০১ & Chem & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আহিত & ১৪০১ & Micro & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber& মোঃ রায়হান & ১৪০১ & Phy & 2nd & চট্টগ্রাম &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মাহিন & ১৪০১ & Chem & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ সালাউদ্দিন & ১৪০১ & ISRT & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মহিরুল & ১৪০১ & ISRT & 3rd & কুড়িগ্রাম &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  অমি & ১২০৩ & Math & 3rd & কিশোরগঞ্জ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আলিমুল & ১৪০৬ & Micro & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ মইনুল & ১২০৩ & Phy & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ হাসান & ১২০৩ & Phy & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ আরিয়ান & ১২০৩ & ISRT & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ এনায়েত & ১১০৩ & Chem & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ ইমরান & ১১০৩ & INFS & 3rd & কুমিল্লা &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  আদনান & ১২০৪ & ISRT & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  মতিউর & ১২০৪ & Phy & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  নাজমুল & ১২০৪ & Math & 3rd & কুমিল্লা &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  মতিউর & ১২০৪ & Phy & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  সায়েম & ১২০৪ & Math & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  সায়েম & ১৫০৭ & Phy & 4th & দিনাজপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  তৌসিফ & ১৫০৭ & Phy & 4th & দিনাজপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  মতিউর & ১২০৪ & Phy & 3rd & ময়মনসিংহ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  সৌমিক & ১৪১০ & CSE & MS & বগুড়া &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  আবিদ & ১৪০৭ & CSE & MS & সাতক্ষীরা &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  তৌকির & ১৪০৭ & CSE & MS & রংপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  তুষার & ১৪০৭ & Micro & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  আরিফ & ১৪০৭ & Math & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  নাজমুল & ১৪০৯ &  & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  নাজমুল & ১৪০৩ & Geology & MS & রংপুর &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  ফয়সাল & ১৪০৩ & Robotics & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  নাঈম & ১৪০৩ & Phy & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  আরাফাত & ১৫০৮ & CSE & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  ফাহিম & ১৫০৯ & EEE & MS & &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  লাইল & ১৫০৯ & & MS & &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  তুহিন & ১৫০২ & EEE & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  জাকারিয়া & ১৩০৬ & INFS & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  রাজীব & ১৩০৬ & CSE & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  রুবেল & ১৫০২ & INFS & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  শওকত & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  শামিম & ১৩০২ &  & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ ড্যানি & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  কাব্য & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  নাজিম & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  ইশতিয়াক & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  মেহেদি & & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  রাফসান & ১৫১০ &  & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  জুলফিকার & & & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  ইবনে সিনা & ১৫১০ & CSE & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  সাগর & ১৩০১ & A.Math & MS &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  আলামিন & ১৫০২ & Zoology & 4th &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\rownumber & মোঃ  মাহবুব & ১৫০২ &  & 3rd &  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The count of `&` in the right hand side is 52. If any one `&` is missing in a line then whole code in un-compileable. And finding the missing `&` line is also difficult. Is there any way to give this as a value (e.g. 52{&})

Comment: If I were you, I would write a simple program and copy-paste the output of the program to the TeX code. Something like `for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) printf("&");` is ok.

Comment: @JouleV For this there is no need to write a program. 52 is not high to count. alongside `wc` is better choice. But, I search for easy solution that can make easy the debugging. The current approach is not good for debugging. Thank you.

Comment: why `\noindent` before the longtable? (it has no affect on the table)

Comment: you only need to do it once, just define `\zz{&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&...52}` then use `\zz` in the table rows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, done. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to do it once, just define

```
\zz{&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&}
```

then use `\zz` in the table rows.